# Using the RTX 3070 laptop GPU for CNN model training with a windows system

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, gpu

I'm trying to use my laptop RTX 3070 GPU for CNN model training because I have to employ a exhastive grid search to tune the hyper parameters. I tried many different methods however, I could not get it done. Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction?

I followed the following procedure.
The procedure:

1. Installed the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 11.2
2. Installed NVIDIA cuDNN 8.1 by downloading and pasting the files (bin,include,lib) into the NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/V11.2
3. Setup the environment variable by including the path in the system path for both bin and libnvvm.
4. Installed tensorflow 2.11 and python 3.8 in a new conda environment.

However, I was unable to setup the system to use the GPU that is available. The code seems to be only using the CPU and when I query the following request I get the below output.

query:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow version: 2.11.0
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Am I missing something here or anyone has the same issue like me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [DirectML](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#tensorflow-directml-plugin-) plugin. *From tensorflow 2.11 Gpu support has been dropped for native windows.* you need to use DirectML plugin.
You can follow the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np11T5-_KhA) to install

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I rolled back to tensorflow 2.10. Now it shows that 1 GPU is available. However, there was no significant increase in the processing speed. I added the following code line to the most computationally expensive section of the code.               
 with tf.device('/GPU:0'):. However, there are some functions and arrays that I have defined out of this computationally expensive section. Could this have an effect?

Comment: I had tried this in Pytorch and It does not work there. You need to run your code and check if it will work (let me know too). Coming to the performance as you have mentioned  you have a laptop GPU, here is the thing about them, Laptop gpu's come with different power capacity, Lately I saw asus selling high gpu like 3070 for cheaper price and I was tempted to buy too until I digged down the specs and found the GPU would function only till 45W / 75W power, which is way too low and technically useless for the crowd looking for high end gpu's. for windows, Run and type dxdiag to check GPU power